# How to insert document in MongoDB with custom object id in Python

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am inserting a document in MongoDB collection using below code:

```
try:
    x = coll.insert_one(data_dict).inserted_id
    print(x)
except Exception as e:
    log.error("Exception at saving data for db {}".format(cid))
    log.error(e)
```

This inserts document in collection and mongo db creates its own object id as shown in below image:

[image]

`_id` is automatically created. Is it possible to insert your own id here. How can we do that.

One way of doing this is to create `_id` in data_dict()

```
data_dict['_id'] = uuid.uuid4()
```

and then save the data in db. This then saves the `_id` with the `uuid` but the data type is also saved as `UUID` and I want to save it as `ObjectID`. Can anyone please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you have to make your own objectid with BSON module.

```
from bson.objectid import ObjectId
```

Then you can create your own objectid and use it for creation or to insert. This should be a comment but I dont have the required rep.